# RavenDb File Storage issue based on 3.0.3 version

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

We have a critical file storage issue of RavenDb.

The context is we have a **Web application server** and a separate **File service server** based on **RavenDB**. The user tries to upload a file with the name of **"xxx_Living #Mapping.pdf"** for example. The web application would then send the request to File server by wrapping the file content into the request body, passing the encoded file name as parameter with Put Action. But all the characters after and includes the **'#'** was blocked upon request received by File Server for unknown network reason, result in **"xxx_Living"**. The file server is able to create file by calling `filesStore.AsyncFilesCommands.UploadAsync(fileName, Request.Body)` without exception.

The issue is we are able to view the File uploaded from Raven.Studio by sending a request **/RavenDbServer/fs/ClientFile/search?query=__directoryName%3A%2Fclientattachments+AND+__level%3A2&start=108&pageSize=27.** (see the snapshot attached)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMpI0.png)

But, We are not able to see the metadata by selecting the target file in the list by sending request **/RavenDbServer/studio/index.html#filesystems/edit?&id=clientattachments%2F0aecef9c-6dd0-4a9e-9df3-039228576471_Living%20&filesystem=clientFile**. (see the snapshot attached)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wswee.png)

We also checked the network flow. the request **RavenDbServer/fs/clientFile/files/clientattachments%2F0aecef9c-6dd0-4a9e-9df3-039228576471_Living%20** returns 404 code.

My question is:

1) Are those kind of files stored successfully in RavenDb File server since we can see the id, file size and Last Modify date in List page, but not able to get it by click into the file from RavenDb studio or download it by calling api `filesStore.AsyncFilesCommands.DownloadAsync(FileName)`?

2) Can we store the file to Raven file server with the file name contains special characters, like '#', or any other ones?